# Linking DKM Projects to Kernel Image(VIP) project as a Sub project/Extra Module in VxWorks Workbench4

Tags: c++, c, vxworks, rtos, wind-river-workbench

How to Link/Load DKM projects with Kernel Image(VIP) project so that i can call the Entry point function of DKM project(application) from Kernel Image project's "usrAppInit.c" to get the application started automatically at boot time? 
Could some one please describe steps or point me to any documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the DKM project as sub-project of your VIP. You can drag and drop, or open the VIP Project Properties, and from Project References check your DKM project
2. In usrAppInit.c, call the entry point of your DKM. You will probably want to include the appropriate header
3. Modify the VIP include paths as required to include the header file.
4. If required, configure the kernel to use the correct build target for the DKM.

Using this approach, when you build the VIP, it will first build the child DKM projects (which will generate the .out files) then the VIP, generating a vxworks image that includes the .out files

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution, but unfortunately this makes a big project with a single binary. My requirement is to have DKM(.out) separately and link it to the Kernel Image Project probably using a build spec macro "EXTRA_MODULES". I tried this but i'm getting the following error:     dld: Redeclaration of __dso_handle
dld: Redeclaration of _ctors
Defined in ../../INT-AC-DKM-18/CD1_AM437X_VSB_ARMARCH7diab/INT-AC-DKM-18/Debug/INT-AC-DKM-18.out
  and        ctdt.o
dld: Redeclaration of _dtors . Any idea how to resolve this conflict?

Comment: No, it will, also generate the DKM .out - check in the DKM build folder. I use this exact process myself. The redeclaration errors you are getting are probably due to including the DKM as both a sub-project, and also as an EXTRA_MODULE. You might also need to force the kernel to use the correct buildspec for the DKM

Comment: You would also need to load the DKM using ld("DKM.out"), before calling the entry function as extern

Comment: @endTunnel not required, as this generates a vxworks image that already has the .out linked into it.

Comment: @mjs: Right. It does have separate ".out's". Thanks for the information. Also i found an other solution to it without having the projects clubbed. Need to specify the DKM application's partial image .o object file path to the EXTRA_MODULES Macro rather than ".out" path. If for example the application is "myApp" , "myapp_partialImage.o" path should be specified in the Macro. Multiple paths can be specified in the Macro with the space if Multiple app needs to be linked.

Comment: @Sukum I hope this helped. If so please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer. If you eventually went with another solution, you could also post your own answer (which you can accept instead, if you wish).

Comment: what happens when i have `a.o`, `b.o` linked with `c_partial.o` into `c.out`...
what should my VIP reference? ro include via Extra_Modules?

Answer (score 0):

An other solution to this problem without having the projects clubbed, Need to specify the DKM application's partial image ".o" object file path to the EXTRA_MODULES Macro rather than ".out" path. If for example the application is "myApp" , "myapp_partialImage.o" path should be specified in the Macro. Multiple paths can be specified in the Macro with the space if Multiple app needs to be linked