# VXWorks Simulation not re-building kernel source code

Tags: kernel-module, simulator, vxworks

Working off of the sample ball Downloadable Kernel Module Project in VXWorks6.9.4.12 Workbench3.3 given in this guide (http://www.cs.utep.edu/isalamah/courses/5372/WR-WB-UserGuide.pdf) on a vxsimulator target with the full network stack setting.

Trying to change the kernel source code (trying the reset some network  components or even just cause a syntax error in the file /vxworks/components/ip_net2-6.9/vxux/daemon/daemon.c), I've noticed that no changes/recompilation takes place even after rebuilding a project or launching a new workbench, and that all the includes for the Kernel Module Project are .h files (for which some depend on the changed deamon.c).

The changes saved from the workbench are showing when I access the files from the command line but the syntax errors added are not stopping TCP code from running properly--any guidance on how to either make these changes take effect or how to go about making changes for a simulator target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to recompile the source of VxWorks itself. This has to be done thru a VxWorks Source Build Project. This is well documented on [docs.windriver.com](https://docs.windriver.com); for example: [Configuring and Building the VxWorks Source Build Project](https://docs.windriver.com/bundle/Wind_River_PPP_Programmers_Guide_6.9_Edition_5_1/page/899187.html).

Comment: Great thanks! The docs say, from there, to create a VIP project based on the new VSB. Can I then create a downloadable kernel module project based off the VIP with a main.c? I tried running main.c from the VIP directly but doesn't seem like an executable kernel process is made

Comment: I have a DKM project that I want to base off this VIP. Is the only way to link it by referencing the DKM in the VIP configuration (like in the link)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456403/linking-dkm-projects-to-kernel-imagevip-project-as-a-sub-project-extra-module